# Unlock ASIX AX88772B USB appearing at boot of Lenovo 710 laptop

Tags: windows, boot, ssd

I have a Yoga 710 laptop (i5 processor). I just removed the 128gb m.2 ssd that it came with and put in a 525gb m.2 ssd. when i booted up with a usb windows install key, the installation went normally.

approximately at the screen where it gives you a 15 second countdown to the first reboot, after the files have been copied and expanded (or something to that effect), I glanced over and the screen had a dos window (blue box with white border all in ASCI text) "Unlock ASIX AX88772B USB" with a password prompt line underneath. I never set a password so don't know what it is referring to.

If I press ESC then I get the same blue DOS style window that says "Confirm: Not unlock device and continue boot?. Press ENTER to confirm, Press Esc to input password"

If i press enter, then the machine boots up normally. But this prompt interrupts every single reboot now.

I've tried reinstalling windows to see if that was it but that did not help.

I don't know if there is some protection against installing a different SSD on this computer / motherboard?

I've looked up online and there seems to be no reference to this message. The model number of the ASIX seems to reference a USB or LAN hardware.

Any thoughts?

Comment: any findings? same issue here.. thx

Comment: no, just have learned to deal with it. sorry

Answer (score 0):

Hit ESC to continue and then hit ENTER to confirm, you'll need to perform this 2 times (on next reboot) while your Windows will continue installing

Comment: And then what??

Answer (score -1):

I am having the same issue. I have determined that the reference is to a usb2 to lan and the laptop has a usb3 to lan. the adaptor I used was a usb 2 version.
Still searching for a way to remove the usb2 driver. the usb3 driver was installed as part of downloading all the other drivers.
I will update if and when I am able to remove or obtain a password.

Comment: This doesn't answer the author's question